# .gitignore is not excluding any files and folder

Tags: git

i'm kind of stuck.

I want to use a gitignore file to exclude files when committing on git.

My gitignore file will exclude folder and files:

```
Presentazione/
pswd/
Temp/
Vertica/
Altro/
Result/
Evaluation/
Data/
.httr-oauth
.Rhistory
OptimalDiscount.Rproj
README_EPROJECT.docx
```

I use notepad to create file, .txt extension with ANSI encoding. Then I rename the file without the .txt extension.
OS: windows

I added to config with `git config --global core.excludesFile ~/.gitignore` .
Still, when i run `git add .` it adds everything .

thanks

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you put this file inside your repository?

Comment: Is this a `.gitignore` in the repository or a global one in your home directory? And note that `.gitignore` only affects *untracked* files.

Comment: In the local repo in my computer where .git folder is located. Files i don't wanna commit are already untracked

Comment: Your choice of words in ‘*already untracked*’ makes me suspect there’s a misunderstanding. Just to make sure: The files you want to ignore are *not* tracked by Git, as in have no history, and show up under `Untracked files:` in the output of `git status`?

Comment: The file must be called `.gitignore` (not `gitignore`, note the `.`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gitignore file's name has to start with a period.  Rename it to `.gitignore` and it should work.

Comment: Btw renaming file to be "extension only" under Windows is kind of tricky ;)

Comment: Probably that was the problem... But also when I rename to be extension only it created a sort of file with no appearent name ( u can see in the screenshot). I might have the feeling that having two files, gitignore.txt and gitignore was causing the issues.